# Re-focusing into the input box closes the dropdown

Tags: angular, ng-bootstrap

I am using NgbTypeahead component of ng-bootstrap. I am facing an issue where dropdown closes if I click in the input box while the focus is already there.

```
<input id="typeahead-template" type="text" class="form-control" 
    [(ngModel)]="model" [ngbTypeahead]="search" [resultTemplate]="rt"
    [inputFormatter]="formatter" />
```

Here are steps and plunker to reproduce the issue:
http://plnkr.co/edit/rxOhDy72YWlLy9U4Ujcd?p=preview

1. Type **al** in the input box, this will open the dropdown,
2. Click in the input box: results in closing the dropdown.

You can keep click inside the input box but the dropdown will stay closed. It will only open if you type an additional word.

Comment: Indeed, this was a problem in our implementation and was fixed in just-released https://github.com/ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap/releases/tag/1.0.0-beta.6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The input gets closed because probably the behaviour comes from NgbTypeahead itself. However, this can be solved if you bind a click event and do stopPropagation on the input.

**src/typeahead-template.html**

```
<input id="typeahead-template" type="text" class="form-control"
   [(ngModel)]="model" [ngbTypeahead]="search" [resultTemplate]="rt"
   [inputFormatter]="formatter" (click)="onClick($event)" />
```

**src/typeahead-template.ts**

```
onClick(event) {
  event.stopPropagation();
}
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/KSXmKOSPCv6OuE6OmzgA?p=preview